# How do I prevent superDevMode from appearing in my arguments?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm using Eclipse (Kepler) for a GWT application and for some reason, superDevMode keeps appearing in my arguments.  We are stuck with GWT 2.4 which does not know what superDevMode is.  I remove the argument, hit Apply and Debug to start the app, but when I look at the arguments again, -superDevMode is in there again.  I am assuming there is some property that belongs to 2.6 (the version that was installed with the Eclipse plugin), but I can't seem to find it.

[image: arguments tab]

**Update:** Below, Adam recommended that I go to the GWT tab and take it out of superdevmode.  Here is a screenshot of that tab:

[image: GWT settings tab]

There isn't a way to do that.  The large area at the top of the tab (above the Super Dev Mode group) suggested that something was supposed to be there, so I set the project's GWT to 2.6.  Sure enough, there was a Super/Classic dev mode selection.  I set it to classic, saved the settings, and then put the project back to 2.4.  The GWT tab looked exactly as it does above and the arguments now has "-nosuperDevMode" in it, which is also not recognized by 2.4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
CC

Comment: What arguments are you talking about?

Comment: In the run/debug configurations for a Web Application, there is an "Arguments" tab.

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary workaround that comes with a caveat: I made the Eclipse Run Configuration file read-only.

Example path:

```
<YOUR_WORKSPACE>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches\<YOUR_RUN_CONFIG_NAME>.launch
```

Then whenever you bring up the Dev Mode Run Configuration in Eclipse it still shows the `-superDevMode` flag, but when you click the Close button it now asks you if you want to save and you can press No.

The big caveat: if you actually do want to change the Run Configuration Eclipse will ask if you want to save, you press Yes, the dialog closes, but it didn't actually save.

Easiest fix is to shutdown Eclipse, manually edit the .launch file to remove `-superDevMode`, make the file read-only, then start Eclipse again.

Here's [the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=314).

Comment: Thanks @Brad.  You basically confirmed my suspicion that there's nothing that we can really do to actually _fix_ this other than wait for an update or wait for the customer to allow us to use a newer GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Go to GWT tab (3rd from left) and switch from Super Development Mode to Classic Development Mode

Comment: Thanks Adam.  I checked there and there is no control allowing me to switch to classic.  I attached a new screenshot to the original post.

Comment: Check if you have something like `<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>` in your module.xml file. If you do have it, try to comment it out.

Comment: I don't seem to have that file anywhere.  Can you give me a hint where it should be?  Thx.

Comment: Right, I should be more specific and write: <module-name>.gwt.xml. It is located in src/<default-package>/. Sorry for that. If, for example, you have project named `SampleProject` and default package named `com.example.SampleProject`, then the file is: `src/com.example.SampleProject/SampleProject.gwt.xml`.

Comment: The linker doesn't exist in our code, so I guess that wasn't it.  Thanks for suggesting it, though.

Comment: That area on the tab doesn't exist for older versions of GWT, but the -superDevMode argument is still inserted by default.